# how to implement validation for phone number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, validation, react-hooks

I've created a form and need to validate field by it's content (empty, !empty) and phone number field so phone number match regex (ukrainian phone number).
this option does not work (

```
  const regex = /^\+[0-9]{3}\s\((\d+)\)-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}/g
  const validate = (username, phone, comment) => {
    if ((username.length === 0 || phone.length === 0, comment.length === 0)) {
   
      setErrorEmpty('the field is empty !')
    
    } else if (!phone.match.regex) {
     
      setPhoneErr('the format is wrong !')
     
    } else {
      setValidated(true)
    }
  }
```

ukrainian number consists of 10 digits: ex:    `0954343333` or `(38)0954343333`

Comment: [Many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+validate+ukrainian+phone+number)

Comment: You should not write a Regex to validate phone numbers. Otherwise, it will soon become hard to maintain for you (developer) and a turn away (bad UX) for end users. And instead, do some simple / basic validation to make sure the user wrote something that looks like a number. The only way to make sure that a phone number is valid or not is by sending an OTP / Code on mobile and asking users to enter that code. Or you should be using a library.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is correct but you need to use the regex correctly.

Here are the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Try this, which asserts if the phone matches the regex:

```
 } else if (!regex.test(phone)) {
```